# Read CSV column values based on column header name in C#

Tags: c#, csv

Could anyone please tell me how to read column data from a csv file ? This csv file has column headers and column values for each work sheet.

In my WPF window, I have 2 list boxes. First list box (lst1) is populated with Column header names. I want to load 2nd list box (lst2) with column values of selected item (column header names) in the first list box.

Here is the code I used for loading column header names in the first list box.

```
    public List<string> ColumnNameGenerator(string FilePath)
    {
        string firstLine = "";
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(FilePath))
        {
            firstLine = reader.ReadLine() ?? "";
        }
        return firstLine.Split(',').ToList();
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        string path = "D:\\Tutorial\\ExcelDocs\\school.csv";
        lst1.ItemsSource = ColumnNameGenerator(path);            
    }
```

And I tried something like to get the column values when we select a header value in the 1st list box.

```
    private void lst1_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var csv = from line in lst1.SelectedItem as List<string>
                  select (line.Split(',')).ToArray();
        lst2.ItemsSource = csv;
    }
```

But it is not working. How it can be done ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: But where do you read the rest of your csv file ? in your 'lst1_SelectionChanged' method you make a link query on the 'SelectedItem' of the 'lst1', which should be the colomn header only, not the values. Try to read the header line in you csv, and store the column id (ie. the index in the 'split(',')'. And when you select a header, read the rest of your csv and take only the split value with the selected index of each lines in your csv

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out a solution for this issue. I used CsvHelper to solve it.

```
  private void lst1_SelectionChanged(object sender, 
                                    SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        lst2.Items.Clear();

        string columnheadername = lst1.SelectedItems[0].ToString();

        CsvConfiguration csvConfiguration = new CsvConfiguration(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
        {
            HasHeaderRecord = true,
            Delimiter = ","
        };

        CsvReader csv = new CsvReader(File.OpenText(path), csvConfiguration);
        csv.Read();
        csv.ReadHeader();

        while (csv.Read())
        {               
            var stringField = csv.GetField<string>(columnheadername);
            lst2.Items.Add(stringField);
        }            
    }
```